# how to get array response from json in string?

Tags: ios, arrays, json, dictionary

I am getting the response from json like this

```
 parcel =     (
                {
            datetime = "2015-08-31 21:48:45";
            height = 2;
            id = 21;
            invoice = NO;
            length = 2;
            mtype = IN;
            "num_item" = 2;
            "parcel_number" = 1;
            pname = "Parcel number - 1";
            "pro_number" = tanu;
            status = 1;
            type = Exact;
            uid = 185;
            weight = 2;
            width = 2;
            wtype = KG;
        }
    );
```

I want to get the height,date time,invoice in a string.. How can this be done? AnyOne can help me for this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSArray * arr_Parcel = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:data];
NSMutableDictionary * temp_Dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
for (int i = 0 ; i < arr_Parcel.count; i++)
    {
        temp_Dict = [arr_Parcel objectAtIndex:i];
         NSString * strHeight = [temp_Dict objectForKey:"height"];
         NSString * strdate = [temp_Dict objectForKey:"datetime"];


     }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Swift, use [SwiftJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) to work with JSON.
It's easy to use. For example:

```
var jsonData = jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
let json = JSON(data: jsonData)
print(json["height"].double) // 2
print(json["datatime"].string) // "2015-08-31 21:48:45"
...
```

Comment: I am using objective C

Answer (score 1):

Create a `NSObject` Class and pass the `NSDictionary` the make a  model class.

```
In your ViewController Class:
```

" parcel" is your Array

```
ModelClass * modelClass = [ModelClass alloc] initWithNewsDictionary: parcel[0]];
```

Create needed variables in `ModelClass.h` Class.

```
-(id)initWithNewsDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.height     = dictionary[@"height"];
        self.datetime   = dictionary[@"datetime"];
        self.invoice    = dictionary[@"invoice"];
        self.weight     = dictionary[@"weight"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
   NSString *height=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[YourJson valueForKey:@"parcel"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"height"]];
   NSString *dateTime=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[YourJson valueForKey:@"parcel"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"datetime"]];
   NSString *invoice=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[YourJson valueForKey:@"parcel"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"invoice"]];
   NSLog(@"height : %@ , date=%@ ,invoice=%@",height,dateTime,invoice);
```